# how to modify camera rotation with trackball controls

Tags: camera, three.js

how would you manually alter the camera rotation with TrackballControls applied to the camera? because it resets the rotation after you do the camera.rotateX(...)

i have found [this ticket](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2719) on the three js issuelist but the person was told to ask on stackoverflow and i see no mention of the problem on stack overflow anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would putting the camera into a container (THREE.Object3D) instead of a scene directly do the trick for you? You could do container.rotateX(...) and it wouldn't be reset by trackball controls. They would be applied within the container.

Comment: good idea! i think the parameters and public methods for the trackball controls are very limited by the way, things like these are a proof of it